# Angular doesn't update the UI after a promise completes

Tags: angular, promise, es6-promise, angular-changedetection

I have the following service:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ContextService {

  contextSubject = new ReplaySubject<ContextModel>(1);

  context: ContextModel = {};

  setContext(context: ContextModel) {
    console.log('contest service set context');
    console.dir(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.contextSubject.next(this.context);
  }

  public get contextObservable(): Observable<ContextModel> {
    return this.contextSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

I have this service injected in a component and I'm subscribing to it.

```
  async ngOnInit() {

    this.contextService.contextObservable.pipe(takeUntil(this.subDestroy)).subscribe(async () => {
      await this.loadData();
    });

  }

  ...

  async loadData() {
    this.loading = true;

    await this.dataSource.query();

    this.loading = false;

    setTimeout(() => { this.cd.detectChanges(); }, 500);
  }
```

which calls an angular material datasource method:

```
  async query():Promise<void> {
...
    let result = await this.inventoryService.query(skip, take, (item : InventoryItem) => { return this.filterFunc(item) }, this.sort);
...
  }
```

which in turn calls a service that returns some dummy data

```
  async query(skip = 0, take = 20, filters : (obj: InventoryItem) => boolean, sort : Sort) : Promise<PagedResult<InventoryItem>> {

    let p = new Promise<PagedResult<InventoryItem>>((resolve, reject) => {
      let res : PagedResult<InventoryItem> = {
        count: 1,
        items: [
          {
            id: '1',
            name: 'a',
            quantity: 123,
            rarity: 'b',
            subtype: 'c',
            type: 'd'
          }
        ],
      };

      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(res);
      }, 1000);
    });

    return p;
  }
```

Then from somewhere I do the following:

```
    this.contextService.setContext({ ... });
```

My problem is the following:
At the first page load everything is fine.
After that if I'm not calling `cd.detectChanges()` the UI stays in a loading state forever or until I click on a form element (input for example).

I don't know if the following matter or not: The top level component is exported as a web component using angular elements. Im using angular material, and I have an angular material table and a progress spinner on the page.

**EDIT**: I actually have to use `setTimeout(() => { this.cd.detectChanges(); }, 500);` to make it work evey time.

Comment: Here: `async query():Promise<void>` - what is returned? (And a side question, is there a good reason for mixing the Observable recipe with the Promise recipe?)

Comment: 1. It returns an empty promise.  and emits a new value to the items observable. I didn't include that code `this.items.next(result.items);` .
2. I like promises better, there was no particular reason